# Need to display price without decimal

Tags: php, formatting, numbers

Im trying to display price of a product, and when the price is a whole value to NOT display the decimal ".00"; But the current result is ALWAYS showing the decimal value.
I have provided my current logic below;

```
$price_value = "20.00"; //coming from DB as string


if (is_int($price_value)) {

   //Display whole number without decimal
   $to_print = number_format($price_value,0);

else {
  //Show the decimal value
  $to_print = number_format($price_value,2);

}

//When I print this value I always get "`20.00`" not "`20`"
```

Comment: Would print(floor($price_value)) work?

Comment: @Mike - that doesn't work when the number is dollars and cents...

Comment: To display a whole number round either up or down .. correct? If it contains cents then dispaly $price_value.

Comment: @Mike - the question (the way I interpret it) is : "When the price is $23.01, display $23.01. When the price is $23.00, display just $23 . No rounding..."

Comment: yes, the rounding has already taken place in my Controller, however the View just displays the result. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is not considered an integer because you converted a string.

See for example:

```
php > var_dump(is_int("23.0"));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(is_int("23"));
bool(false)
php > var_dump(is_int(23));
bool(true)
```

You can instead do the following:

```
if( abs($price_value - floor($price_value)) < 0.001 )
  //Display whole number without decimal
  $to_print = number_format($price_value,0);
else {
  //Show the decimal value
  $to_print = number_format($price_value,2);
}
```

the 0.001 takes account of any rounding errors in converting strings to decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Try just removing the '0' parameter. It defaults to it anyway.

If that doesn't work and you insist on doing it, you could add all arguments:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

And set the dec_point to a character value that you can use to split, and then return the string up until that point. First check if the first idea works though.

Comment: The formatting is not the problem - it is the test whether the number is a round dollar amount.

Comment: it's not the test, its the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use to print value without decimal

```
$to_print = (int) $price_value;
```

Comment: I still needed the decimal value if it existed

Answer (score 0):

rather than `is_int()` (which returns false work on strings), consider using `fmod()`:

```
$price_value = "20.00";
if (fmod($price_value,1) === 0.0)
    $to_print = number_format($price_value,0);
else
    $to_print = number_format($price_value,2);
```

It probably doesn't work as well for higher-precision numbers, but I tested it with a few reasonable price values and it seems to work okay.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this little class : https://github.com/johndodev/MoneyFormatter